# Cut down the length of array based on its index in a column

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe similar like this:

```
    signal
0   0.469112    -0.282863 -1.509059 -1.135632   1.212112    -0.173215   0.119209  -1.044236 
1   0.469152    0.32863    1.509059  1.135632   1.212112     0.173215   0.419209  -1.044236 
2   0.469152    0.32843    1.209059  5.135632   6.212112    -0.173215   -0.419209 -7.044236
```

Expected output:

```
 signal
0    -1.509059  -1.135632   1.212112    -0.173215   0.119209        
1    1.509059    1.135632   1.212112     0.173215   0.419209        
2    1.209059    5.135632   6.212112    -0.173215   -0.419209
```

I want to loop through column "signal" (array) and select the data which inputs falls between the third and fifth in each row. In the real dataset, the length of signal in each row varies from 10 to 8000. I tried something like df.signal.iloc[3:5], but it does not work. So how can I do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you need indexing by `str`:

```
df.signal.str[2:7]
```

Pandas count from `0`, so for select from `3.` to `6.` column use:

```
df1 = df.signal.str[2:6]
print (df1)
0    [-1.509059, -1.135632, 1.212112, -0.173215]
1       [1.509059, 1.135632, 1.212112, 0.173215]
2      [1.209059, 5.135632, 6.212112, -0.173215]
Name: signal, dtype: object
```

Comment: @jezrale  Thanks! I tried to apply to the whole column in the dataframe like this: df.singal.apply(lambda x : x.str[300:1300]) and got this 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'str'

Comment: @almo - Why `apply` ? Use `df.singal.str[300:1300]`